# characters.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues mapping through this data. I've read that it is likely that the data type is wrong, but I'm ten days into Js. I'm not so sure.

```
const App = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCharacters = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`https://api.got.show/api/show/characters/${query}`)

      setCharacters(result.data)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }

    fetchCharacters();
  }, [query])

  return <div className="container">
    <Header />
    <Search getQuery={(q) => setQuery(q)}/>
    <CharacterGrid isLoading={isLoading} characters={characters}/>
  </div>

}

const CharacterGrid = ({ characters, isLoading }) => {
    return isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />) : (
        <section className="cards">
        {characters.map(character => (
            <CharacterItem key={character.id} character={character}></CharacterItem>
        ))}
    </section>)
}
```

Comment: what is the `characters` data type?

Comment: characters is not an array. Definitely. Before return line, add `console.log(characters)` and let us know what you see. It's not an array though!

Comment: We will need more code to be able to help you, like the place where you are creating the variable that you are passing as the characters prop for instance

Comment: Sorry guys, I added the rest of the code. @seesharper I get back all the characters data from the api.

Comment: @Nih.ilus yes, but it's not the type you expect. Please put in that log to see.

Comment: @Nih.ilus, maybe initially you had set characters to array data type but fetchCharacters()  overridden with object. We have to see the response given by api. Is it returning an array.

Comment: It would be good if you can just console out the characters API data. I think the data returned from the API is an object and that is been passed to the CharacterGrid component and you are trying to map over an object which is giving the error.You can just console result.data inside the useEffect to check

Comment: I think you're right, t is returning undefined. @Erick What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Since the results.data is undefined, you can add a check to prevent the state updation.
This check would atleast allow your app to work even if characters array is undefined.
The code snippet written below would show a loading screen. So I have disabled it by keeping the setIsLoading outside the condition.
You must ensure that the characters is been returned from the API so that the CharacterGrid component gets rendered with the list.
You can also check whether the result returned in response from the API is correct by just doing a console after the APi call.I have added it in the code snippet for verifying

```
const App = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCharacters = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`https://api.got.show/api/show/characters/${query}`);
      console.log('result',result);
      if(result && result.data) {
          setCharacters(result.data)
      }
      setIsLoading(false)
    }

    fetchCharacters();
  }, [query])

  return <div className="container">
    <Header />
    <Search getQuery={(q) => setQuery(q)}/>
    <CharacterGrid isLoading={isLoading} characters={characters}/>
  </div>

}

const CharacterGrid = ({ characters, isLoading }) => {
    return isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />) : (
        <section className="cards">
        {characters && characters.map(character => (
            <CharacterItem key={character.id} character={character}></CharacterItem>
        ))}
    </section>)
}
```